# Github Pages favicon not showing (using png)

Tags: github-pages, favicon

Using Github Pages to publish a site. I used favicon.io to generate pngs/links.
The favicon works locally, but not on Github pages.
**Can I get the favicon working (utilizing .png)?**

Code in my :

```
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png:/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png"/>
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest"/>
```

[Repo file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ejrJ.png)

Comment: Microsoft Edge do not show favicon for many sites.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in the right place,i.e, inside the `head` tag, and then also not working, then I think the problem is with the directory.
As your GitHub repository link is not given, so I can not say the exact answer.
But if your GitHub pages link look like this, [`example.github.io`](https://example.github.io), then you are right and I do not know the exact reason.
But if the link looks like this,[`example.github.io/repository`](https://example.github.io/repository)(the repository link is included), then try changing the directory, such that,

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="./apple-touch-icon.png"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./favicon-32x32.png:/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./favicon-16x16.png"/>
<link rel="manifest" href="./site.webmanifest"/>
```